# Is it ok to hot swap a Dictionary without synchronization that is only ever read-accessed from multiple threads?

Tags: c#

I have a configuration repository class that roughly looks like this:

```
public class ConfigurationRepository // pseudo c#
{
   private IDictionary<string, string> _cache = new Dictionary<string, string>();
   private ConfigurationStore _configStore;
   private CancellationToken cancellationToken;

   public ConfigurationRepository(ConfigurationStore configStore, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
      _configStore = configStore;
      _cancellationToken = cancellationToken;

      LiveCacheReload();
   }

   private void LiveCacheReload()
   {
      Task.Run(() => 
         while(!_cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
         {
            try {
               _cache = new Dictionary<string, string>(_store.GetAllItems(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            } catch {} // ignore

            // some exponential back-off code here
         }
      );
   }

   ... get methods ...
}
```

... where `_cache` is only ever accessed in a read-only manner through `_cache.ContainsKey(key)`, `_cache.Keys`, and `_cache[key]`.

This class is accessed from multiple threads. Is it ok to hot swap this Dictionary without synchronization when it is only  ever read-accessed? `ConfigurationProvider` from `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` looks to be implemented in the same way.

Comment: It depends. If code does something like `if (_cache.ContainsKey(key)) { var x = _cache[key]; }` that's obviously unsafe, because `_cache` could be re-assigned between the first and second reads.

Comment: @canton7 good point. I see that Microsoft uses `.TryGetValue(key, out value);` instead which probably addresses that issue.

Comment: I would at least consider just using a concurrentDictionary and call Clear.

Comment: Two points - 1) It is unsafe when you talk about multiple threads. On a side note, you can look for ConcurrentDictionary for thread safe access. 2) Instead of swapping the Dictionary object, what about clearing and adding new values using AddRange method?

Comment: I'm also slightly worried that your `LiveCacheReload` appears to sit in an infinite tight loop constantly re-assigning `_cache` (until cancelled)

Comment: @canton7 there is some backoff code there, ill update the question

Comment: @user1672994 1) Can you elaborate on why it is unsafe? 2) that approach would definitely require a lock around the Dictionary (or ConcurrentDictionary) because the dictionary would now be read/write accessed.

Comment: Note if you used a ConcurrentDictionary, add/remove operations are thread-safe, so you wouldn't need a separate lock to do these

Comment: @canton7 would I need a separate lock to hot swap the concurrentdictionary?

Comment: Yes. The ConcurrentDictionary is only thead-safe when you actually interact with it. If you're re-assigning a field on another class which happens to point to a `ConcurrentDictionary`, that's got nothing to do with the `ConcurrentDictionary` itself, and so will need a separate lock

Answer (score 3):

It depends. If you have code which does something like:

```
if (_cache.ContainsKey(key))
{
    var x = _cache[key];
}
```

that's obviously unsafe, because `_cache` could be re-assigned between the first and second reads.

If the consumer code only ever accesses `_cache` once (and creates a local copy if it needs to do multiple accesses), it's safe in the sense that you shouldn't get a crash. However you need to carefully audit every place where `_cache` is accessed to make sure that the code doesn't make any assumptions about `_cache`.

However, there's no memory barrier around reading or writing `_cache`, which means that a thread reading `_cache` may read a value which is old: the compiler, JIT and even CPU are allowed to return a value which was read some time ago. For example, in a tight loop which reads `_cache` on every iteration, the JIT may re-arrange instructions so that `_cache` is read once just before the loop, and then never re-read inside the loop. Likewise a CPU cache local to one processor core may contain an out-of-date value for `_value`, and the CPU is under no obligation to update this if another core writes a different value through a different cache.

To avoid this, you need a memory barrier, and the safest way to introduce one is through a lock.

So, don't be clever and try and avoid locks. It's fraught: lock-free code is really hard to write correctly, but it's very very easy to write something which *appears* to work, and then causes a subtle error in very particular circumstances which is impossible to track down. It's just not worth the risk.

For an eye-opening read, try Eric Lippert's post [Can I skip the lock when reading an integer?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/12/can-i-skip-the-lock-when-reading-an-integer/) (and the follow-up article linked at the bottom).